# Converting Codeigniter query to Laravel

Tags: codeigniter, laravel-5

I have a database table name admin_menu with following schema
[image]

In Codeigniter I use a function in my model to get the navigation in an associative array (which I can easily iterate and render a menu) as follows

```
public function getMenuItems()
{
    $st=$this->db->select('*')->from('admin_menu')->where('parent',0)->get()->result_array();
    if(count($st)>0)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($st);$i++)
        {
            $st[$i]['child']=$this->db->select('*')->from('admin_menu')->where('parent',$st[$i]['id'])->get()->result_array();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $st;
}
```

It gives me an Array like this

```
Array
(
[menu] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Users
                [class] => icon icon-users
                [url] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [child] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [name] => Add
                                [class] => 
                                [url] => admin/add_user
                                [parent] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [name] => Manage
                                [class] => 
                                [url] => admin/manage_users
                                [parent] => 1
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

How Sweet. Now In Laravel 5.2, I created a Model adminNav along with Migration, same database schema for admin_nav table. In my Controller's index function I used following code

```
public function index($name=NULL)
{
    $adminNav=new adminNav();
    $navs=$adminNav->all();
    $parents=$adminNav->WHERE('parent',0)->get();
    for($i=0;$i<count($parents);$i++)
    {
        $child=$adminNav->WHERE('parent',$parents[$i]['id'])->get()->toArray();
        $parents[$i]['child']=$child;
    }

    return View('partials.form',[
                                    'navs'=>$navs,
                                    'parents'=>$parents, 
                                ]);
}
```

And I was punished by a huge list of parameters i was not ready for like this

```
  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
  (
  [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\adminNav Object
            (
                [connection:protected] => 
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [name] => Users
                        [url] => 
                        [updated_at] => 2017-03-04 05:47:07
                        [created_at] => 2017-03-04 05:47:07
                        [child] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 6
                                        [parent] => 1
                                        [name] => Add
                                        [url] => adminController/add_user
                                        [updated_at] => 2017-03-04 09:26:26
                                        [created_at] => 2017-03-04 09:26:26
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 7
                                        [parent] => 1
                                        [name] => Manage
                                        [url] => adminController/manage_users
                                        [updated_at] => 2017-03-04 09:29:16
                                        [created_at] => 2017-03-04 09:29:16
                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

Notice that I used toArray() function to get Child and it works perfectly and gives me a simple array at child's index but when I try to use the same function when getting parents like this

```
$parents=$adminNav->WHERE('parent',0)->get()->toArray();
```

it gives me an error

[image]

How can I get the result in an Array instead of Object or am I asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AdminNav` model add a `hasMany` relationship to itself, which describes it's children.

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(AdminNav::class, 'parent', 'id');
}
```

You have to add a scope to fetch only parent navs from the model.

```
public function scopeRoot($query) {
    return $query->where('parent', 0);
}
```

Then in your code you can simply use `AdminNav::with('children')->root()->get()->toArray()`

Haven't tested it yet, but I guess it will work.

Answer (score 1):

To get a like-for-link query in Laravel you could do:

```
public function getMenuItems()
{
    $st = DB::table('admin_menu')->where('parent', 0)->get()->toArray();

    if (count($st) < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($st); $i++) {
        $st[$i]['child'] = DB::table('admin_menu')->where('parent', $st[$i]['id'])->get()->toArray();
    }

    return $st;
}
```

Or

```
public function getMenuItems()
{
    $st = DB::table('admin_menu')->where('parent', 0)->get()
        ->map(function ($item) {

            $item->child = DB::table('admin_menu')->where('parent', $item['id'])->get()->toArray();

            return $item;
        })->toArray();

    return count($st) ? $st : false;
}
```

That being said I would suggest using @Mithredate answer as it will be more efficient and easier to write.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No doubt using Eloquent in Laravel is always better than query builder.